# How do I install arbitrary .app iPhone applications to jailbroken iPhones?

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning, jailbreak

I have apps pending app-store submission, and I'd like to be able to test them easily sans creating any special builds or creating provisioning profiles for specific phones or ad-hoc distributions.

How can I take this distribution-ready `.app` application and use it on jailbroken iPhones? I tried `scp`ing the file to `/Applications`, but on re-spring, the application doesn't have gloss and it crashes as soon as I open it, which seems like a likely provisioning/signing issue.

How can I easily deploy on jailbroken iPhones? What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fake code-sign your app so that it can run on jail broken iPhones. [Here is an URL](http://ihackmyi.com/topic/74467-how-to-fake-code-sign-applications-in-xcode/) for how to do it.

Comment: Here's the tricky part: A third party is building and signing my app. Is there no way to do this without changing the signing process in Xcode?

Comment: I don't know another way for this. Sorry

Comment: Well that sucks. The third party also builds android apps from the same base, so at least I can test that directly!